# scikit-learn/svm - fetch probabilities and associated labels after 'predict_proba'

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, libsvm

I am using the scikit-learn SVM for text classification and following the guideline [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html). But I am confused as to how to use the `predict_proba` method to fetch the probabilities, associate with the correct label and fetch the top 3.

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
clf = svm.SVC(probability=True,class_weight='balanced')

test_data = [...]

test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
predicted = clf.predict_proba(test_vectors)
for doc, pred in zip(test_labels, predicted):
    print('%r => %s' % (doc, test_labels[pred]))
```

On running the above code I get this exception:

> TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an
>   index

This is understandable since the test_labels is an array of probabilities, but I am not sure how to fetch the associated label and probability.

Comment: Please post the full error stack trace. On which line are you getting the error? And also show some samples of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing and it worked out for me. Hope this would be helpful to someone:

```
    clf = cPickle.load(...)  
    test_data, test_labels = load_testfiles(_testpath) 

    for td in zip(test_data,test_labels):
        X = vectorizer.transform([td[0]])
        label = td[1]
        res = clf.predict_proba(X)[0]
        # sd = np.std(res)
        # max = np.amax(res)
        # min = np.amin(res)
        # mean = np.mean(res)
        # median = np.median(res)
        print("test--->actual=",label,"pred=",res)
```